# Add SFMC_ID to GA360 without query string parameter

Tags: marketing-cloud, google-analytics

I have integrated SFMC with GA360 with the standard connector but I would like to pass the SFMC_ID directly to GA360 without using the query string parameter. Is there any function, such as

ga('send', {[...]} );

to send SFMC_ID to GA360 (instead of the query string parameter)?

Comment: Not that I’ve found. The only way to get SubKey into GA is via the GA Collect.js. Is there any reason you are trying to avoid using URL parameters?

Comment: We would like to avoid the data collection limit based on email's post click and force the valorization of the SFMC during the login.